# Why is my Swift code not correctly calculating scores based on values in .json data

Tags: json, swift

Let me start by saying that I am new to programming and therefore this is probably just a silly newbie error. I did try and find the answer online, but perhaps I'm not searching for the right things as I couldn't find a solution.

In a nutshell I am trying to calculate a score within a trivia game app based on a number of variables. One of those variables determines a 'value' for the question being answered based on data within a .json file. That is, all the questions, answers, values etc are stored in the .json file.

The .json file is in the following format:

```
[
  {
  "id":"1",
  "question":"Which planet do we live on?",
  "answers":[
             "Earth",
             "Mars",
             "Venus",
             "Jupiter"
             ],
  "difficulty":"Beginner",
  "value":"1"
  },
  {
  "id":"2",
  "question":"In what year did the Prime Minister of Australia literally just vanish?",
  "answers":[
             "1967",
             "1975",
             "2001",
             "1939"
             ],
  "difficulty":"Hardest",
  "value":"6"
  },
```

And the .json data continues that way for hundreds of questions.

Now within my Swift code I am loading my .json data this way:

```
func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
{
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("trivia", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
    //println(allEntries)

}
```

I have also declared the following variables:

```
var questionvalue :String?
var currentgoals :Int! = 0
var currentbehinds :Int! = 0
var currenttotal :Int! = 0
```

And the code I am using to load my questions is:

```
func LoadQuestion(index : Int)
{
    let entry : NSDictionary = shuffledQuestions[index] as! NSDictionary
    let question : NSString = entry.objectForKey("question") as! NSString
    let arr : NSMutableArray = entry.objectForKey("answers") as! NSMutableArray

    let questionvalue : NSString = entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! NSString

    let QID : NSString = entry.objectForKey("id") as! NSString



    if let a = arr.objectAtIndex(0) as? String {
        self.answertext = a
    }
```

Now to the scoring. Scoring involves 'goals', 'behinds' and a 'total'. A goal is worth 6 points and a behind is worth 1 point. Depending on the difficulty of the question, a user can score either 1, 2, 3 or 4 behinds or a goal.

The relevant bit of code for my scoring is as follows:

```
func CheckAnswer( answerNumber : Int)
{
    if(answerNumber == currentCorrectAnswerIndex)
    {
        // we have the correct answer


        if questionvalue == "Beginner" {currentbehinds = currentbehinds+1}
        else{
            if questionvalue == "Easy" {currentbehinds = currentbehinds+2}
            else{
                if questionvalue == "Intermediate" {currentbehinds = currentbehinds+3}
                else{
                    if questionvalue == "Hard" {currentbehinds = currentbehinds+4}
                else{
                    if questionvalue == "Hardest" {currentgoals = currentgoals+1}
                }
            }
        }
        }

        labelCurrentGoals.text = "\(currentgoals)"
        labelCurrentBehinds.text = "\(currentbehinds)"
        labelCurrentTotal.text = "\(currenttotal)"
        currenttotal = (currentgoals*6) + currentbehinds
```

As you can see, the actual calculations are done within my Swift code, they're not done using the data from the .json file. I just want to reference either the "difficulty" or "value" stored in the .json file as a means to determine which calculation within Swift the app uses. However, whenever the user gets a correct answer, the score values all remain at zero.

I have also tried using the data stored in the "value" label from my .json file by changing the `var questionvalue :String?` to `var questionvalue :Int!` and changing the `let questionvalue : NSString = entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! NSString` in my LoadQuestion function to `let questionvalue : NSInteger = entry.objectForKey("value") as! Int` and changing my CheckAnswer function so that it's referencing these values instead (i.e. "1" instead of "Beginner", and so on).

I have also tried changing the data within my .json file so that the numeric values were not strings.

But alas none of this works. As a newbie I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find the answer. I suspect I'm not searching for the right thing, either here or on Google. If that's the case, I'd appreciate some links to check out. Or, if it's as straightforward as I suspect, a solution to my code would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to clearly write out your problem. I'm guessing that the JSON is being loaded correctly because you are force-casting and not crashing. This is going to be a long answer showing you how I would debug your problem.

I would start debugging in your `CheckAnswer` function because that's where you're changing and calculating the score. At the beginning, temporarily add the following code to print out the values of `answerNumber`, `currentCorrectAnswerIndex` and `questionvalue`.

```
print("Answer Number: \(answerNumber)")
print("Currently Correct Idx: \(currentCorrectAnswerIndex)")
print("Question Value: \(questionvalue)")
```

The key to debugging is making sure that your variables (program state) are what you expect them to be. If nothing is printed to the console (the bottom tab of Xcode) then CheckAnswer isn't being called. If `answerNumber` is not the same as `currentCorrectAnswerIndex` then your inner statement isn't being called. If `questionvalue` isn't one of your possible values then you may need to check all of the places where you think you set that value.

Spoiler:

> questionvalue is going to be nil

So you found a value that's unexpected, what do you do? First thing is question your assumptions. You assume that variable is set/modified somewhere else but it clearly isn't. Check everywhere you think the value is set/modified. Sometimes you'll have to do this multiple times going deeper and deeper into your code.

Solution:

> In `LoadQuestion`, you get the value of the question from JSON and assign it to a local variable.
>  `let questionvalue : NSString = entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! NSString`.
>  That questionvalue is a different questionvalue than the one at the top of the page (`var questionvalue :String?`).
>  You can assign that value by removing the let; now you reference the variable in your class instead of the local variable in the `LoadQuestion` function
>  `questionvalue = entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! NSString`

Also, here are some programming things that you might not be aware of. `else if` can be used if you have several distinct conditions that you want to test. The `a += b` is shorthand syntax for `a = a + b` (this gets done a lot so programmers came up with this shortcut).

```
if questionvalue == "Beginner" {currentbehinds += 1}
else if questionvalue == "Easy" {currentbehinds += 2}
else if questionvalue == "Intermediate" {currentbehinds += 3}
else if questionvalue == "Hard" {currentbehinds += 4}
else if questionvalue == "Hardest" {currentgoals += 1}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for going through the debugging process. That's very helpful. And you're right, I wasn't aware of `else if` - that should make my code a lot cleaner in quite a few places! Now, I didn't mention this in my question (my fault!), but I had already tried changing my code in LoadQuestion by removing the 'let', but in doing so Xcode generated an error. However, I tried this again and was prompted to change it to: `questionvalue = entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! NSString as String` (i.e. add 'as String' to the end. And this worked!! Thank you! :)

Comment: Also, thank you for explaining that my original `let questionvalue : NSString = entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! NSString` was actually not assigning a value to the variable I had declared earlier. That's another learning for me. :)

Comment: Because `questionvalue` is a `String`, you can't assign an `NSString` value to it. You can cast the type `NSString` to `String` by using `as String` so that's why `as! NSString as String` works. You could actually just force cast to `String`. Eg. `entry.objectForKey("difficulty") as! String`